# Android Checkbox ticked change activity

Tags: android, redirect, android-activity, checkbox

I am just wondering if it is possible to change to another activity, after a checkbox has been ticked, and once its ticked it goes to that activity after 5 seconds or loads something that says please wait then changes. And if that activity has been returned to the checkbox is not checked anymore.

I havent got any code because i was just reading around documentation and havent found anything so just want to know if anyone has done something similar and if they could share please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
checkBox.setChecked(false); //put this in onResume() or onCreate() or something

checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    FirstActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                }, 5000); //wait for 5 seconds
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think this method will cause issue... when you perform check and uncheck operations frequently within 5 seconds. Please confirm that it causes any issue or not... It may open multiple activities in stack and when you will press back button then also you will see the same screen...

Comment: Either add a flag for checking that the activity was already started queue to be started or use launchMode of singleTop to avoid having multiple activities. No sure what is the use case of doing the delayed but anyway!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you may want to do this either in [onCheckListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener)) or the [onClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) and start the next activity with `startActivity(intent)`

If you need to delay the you may want to use a `Handler.postDelayed` method but not entirely sure If I understood your workflow so please try to explained it a bit more detail.